# Number next to a Guardian's name?

Tags: destiny-2

Since Beyond Light I noticed that there is a number next to a Guardian's name. (Before the update, the blue box used to hold the equipped class of the player.)

[image]

When I die and am waiting for respawn, I always see that my number is **1**, so I don't think it is the Season Pass level, but then again it may simply be a bug. So, what does this number mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That number is your Season Rank. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/jrcumc/destiny_2_beyond_light_new_light_information_hub/) Reddit thread indicates it does seem to be a bug where it displays your Season Rank as 1 regardless of what your actual Season Rank is whenever you are dead and waiting to be revived

Comment: I believe that bug is since fixed. Seasonal rank is displayed correctly now

Comment: @n_plum Interesting. I haven't seen any patch notes for it, so can't confirmed at the moment. I'll confirm that when I play later today

Comment: @n_plum Doesn't appear to be fixed. When I played Destiny 2 last night, my season rank still displayed as 1 when I was waiting to be revived

Comment: What platform are you on? On PC I haven't seen the 1 displayed Season Rank in a while, I see everyone's varying season ranks next to their names.

Comment: @n_plum I'm on PS4. I checked for new updates and I have the latest version available. I wonder if some updates are being rolled out to PC prior to console?